# Create a migration for adding 2 instances

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a task to create a  migration for adding 2 instances of WorkRoom into database, I've already create a migration when created the Model and added to table 3 fields, I don't understand what migration should I do now.

```
class CreateWorkRoomsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('work_room', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('building')->nullable();
            $table->integer('floor')->nullable();
            $table->integer('office_number')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('work_room');
```

Comment: Actually inserting records into the database isn't done via migrations, its done via seeds. See the docs for more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/seeding

Comment: @TimLewis thank you for your response, I know about seeding, this is why I didn't uderstand the task my mentor gave to me and I decided to ask here, as I am a beginner in laravel, thought that maybe there is something I didn't know yet about migrations.

Comment: No worries! Perhaps your mentor is wanting you to do migrations and seeding at the same time, which can be accomplished via `php artisan migrate --seed`, or `php artisan migrate` followed by `php artisan db:seed`, etc etc. But you still need to set up the seeder files.